# Call WCF another SharePoint server web service list (UpdateListItem)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

Prompt as through Sharepoint Designer to be connected to WCF of other Sharepoint the server (it is necessary to connect the list of other server to do UpdateListItem)? In the attached file at me an error in case of connection?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem with some subsite 
you have to point the Web service submit to site not to server directly.

It should be like this  `http://share/yoursite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx`

Comment: Error: There was an error generating the XML document. 
Maybe there's another way to connect to the sharepoint list through SharePoint designer, to be able to change the elements of the list ?

Comment: yes, there is another way I will update my answer with how to update list item using workflow  but first tell me is this list in the same site that have the workflow ?

Comment: I need to connect a list of other sharepoint server 2010 (other domain)

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding , but you didn't mention that at your question anyway, I only tried to help you. I will continue to find solution, but should you try to navigate first to http://share/yoursite/_vti_bin/lists.asmx from your browser may be the issue at the other farm

Comment: Yes , actually it is cross-source query that I want to get around in different ways.